# RabbitMQ + Celery: Number of connections per celery worker

Tags: flask, celery

I am trying to deploy a web application (still a beginner and learning) and I am having trouble figuring out what is going on. My application is written using Flask and there is are several functions which I need to run in a loop, essentially feeding off one another. In order to not slow down the application I am using Celery. On my local machine I used Redis as the broker but moving forward I want to use RabbitMQ. I have already set this all up on my virtual machine but the issue I keep running into is that the 1 celery worker that I run creates 3 connections and I believe this is creating an issue with those functions I mentioned earlier.

You see, those functions are run before the first request the application receives. However, I think that because of the 3 connections the 1 celery worker is creating before first request  tasks are being run several times. This does not happen on my local machine, here everything works as intended.

Does anyone have any thoughts? Is this the 3 connections that are being created? If so, how can I tell the celery worker to not make more than 1 connection?

EDIT: Since posting I have setup Celery with RabbitMQ on my local machine using the same settings as on the virtual machine. Upon testing, the application works as intended when run from my local machine. Perhaps this is not an issue with the channels?

Comment: 1. connection to where? 2. can you share your celery worker command?

Comment: Celery uses the redis database to store a queue of tasks that need to be completed, if the worker shuts down and starts back up again, the worker will look into the queue for what needs executed next. It sounds like you might need to flush a backlog of tasks in your local redis database using the `redis-cli flushall`